# Bounded Function displaying address in Python

Tags: function, class, python-3.x

```
class NonVerticalLine:

    def __init__(self, point_1, point_2):

            self.point_1=point_1
            self.point_2=point_2


    def slope(self):

            p1=self.point_1
            p2=self.point_2
            return (p2.y-p1.y)/(p2.x-p1.x)
```

When i pass the value to _init and access function slope it gives--->

```
>>> from quiz_5 import *

>>> p1 = Point(1,2)

>>> p2 = Point(4,4)

>>> line = NonVerticalLine(point_1 = p1, point_2 = p2)

>>> line.slope
<bound method NonVerticalLine.slope of <quiz_5.NonVerticalLine object at 0x105b00160>>
```

It should be 0.6666666666666666

Comment: it gives > bound method NonVerticalLine.slope of <quiz_5.NonVerticalLine object at 0x105b00160>>

Comment: You haven't called the function. Try `line.slope()`.

Comment: I am supposed to do that way---> Line.slope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, try

```
class NonVerticalLine:

    def __init__(self, point_1, point_2):

            self.point_1=point_1
            self.point_2=point_2

    @property
    def slope(self):

            p1=self.point_1
            p2=self.point_2
            return (p2.y-p1.y)/(p2.x-p1.x)
```

The `@property` decorator is used to implement getters and setters in Python, so `line.slope` would be equivalent to `line.slope()` without the decorator. In this case it seems that this behaviour is what you want.

Comment: Exactly what i want (y)